# How to set min datetime in column chart highcharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts, column-chart

I try to set min xAxis datetime type in column chart, there isn't anything show up!.
How i set min datetime for column chart?

```
xAxis: {
    type:"datetime",
    tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
    min:1640970000000,
    crosshair: true
},
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzt2chvu/3/)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have unsorted data. You need to sort the data in ascending X order.

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [...].reverse()
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bdgctzuw/

**Error info:** https://assets.highcharts.com/errors/15/